# Редактор под mac для PHP, HTML, JS, CSS

Tags: mac, редактор

Пробую перейти на mac. Посоветуйте редактор.

Требования:

- доступ по SFTP (не плагином, а изначально "в комплекте"),
- utf-8,
- подсветка кода php, js, html и сss,
- бесплатный (желательно, но можно и платный не дороже ~$20-$50 единоразово),
- под Mac!

Не нужна IDE и т.п. Нужно что-нибудь простое, симпатичное и функциональное в рамках изложенных выше требований. Спасибо :)

**UPDATE (спустя почти 7 лет после создания вопроса): кстати, я тогда остановился на [Coda](https://www.panic.com/coda/) и до сих под очень доволен им. Под мои запросы подошел идеально :)**

Comment: Автодополнение играет роль?   
И еще: вы имеете в виду бесплатный или *бесплатный*?

Comment: внятное автодополнение будет плюсом, но в принципе особо роли не играет. Имеется в виду "честно бесплатный" :) Я в принципе готов и купить редактор, но уверен, что есть и бесплатные ничем не хуже, чем за деньги.

Comment: Vim. Подсветка не только php, js, html, css (с остальным тоже д.б. нормально)

Comment: Насчет плагинов: почти везде в макоси они реализутся в виде "скопировал плагин в папку приложения и забыл", так что проблем не вижу с их использованием.

Comment: Так же рекомендую **Codelobster IDE**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Список того, что сам использовал (не web-dev, но не суть):

1. [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2). Отличная штука, умеет почти все, что можно захотеть + куча плагинов (для того же SFTP), которые легко [гуглятся](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp). Не бесплатный, но можно пользоваться сколь угодно долго, только периодически (через каждые 10-15 сохранений) закрывать окошко с предложением купить.
2. [TextMate](http://macromates.com/). В узких кругах считается "Mac-way vim". Умеет все из коробки, куча плагинов, стоит денег.
3. [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html?utm_source=df&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=bbedit). Тоже мощная весчь. Платный.
4. [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/). Это lite-версия `BBEdit`. Нет поддержки `SFTP` и еще чего-то.
5. [Kod](http://kodapp.com/). Очень приятный, бесплатный. Но последняя версия - альфа 0.0.3, и обновлятся, видимо, не будет.
6. [Chocolat](http://chocolatapp.com/). Еще более приятный редактор. Нет SFTP, бесплатный только пока не выйдет из беты. *Есть real-time проверка ошибок для `PHP` и `JavaScript`*.
7. [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/). Пожалуй, самый продвинутый редактор именно для веб-разработки. Даже не просто редактор, а целый комбайн (однако вовсе не монструозный - работать одно удовольствие). Платный.
8. [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/). По функционалу если и уступает Coda, то лишь в каких-то очень специфичных и редко используемых возможностях. Платный.
9. [Taco HTML Edit](http://www.tacosw.com/htmledit/). Умеет работать с `HTML`,  `JavaScript` и `PHP`. Платный.

Я не рассматривал всякие кроссплатформенные штуки, вроде `Aptana` и `Eclipse`.
Советую также попробовать `vim` и `emacs` - "из коробки" есть все, что нужно, функциональны более чем. Есть GUI-версии, вроде [`MacVim`](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) и [`Aquamacs`](http://aquamacs.org/).

Comment: присмотрюсь к coda. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю:

- Sublime Text 2 - плагины на Python. Добротная вещ.
- VIM (iTerm) или же MacVIM